# What we are looking for is to run ROS 2 Galactic on an isolated ECU and record data as ROS2 bags

Tags: ros2

What we are looking for is to run ROS 2 Galactic on an isolated ECU and record in ROS 2 bags.

On the PC we will be using different ROS 2 distributions Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS 2 Foxy and Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS 2 Humble.

Either way we need to support both ROS 2 Foxy and ROS 2 Humble.
By this we already have three different ROS 2 distributions in our setup. So our question is will there be compatibility for the ROS 2 bags between the three ROS 2 Galactic and ROS 2 Humble and ROS 2 Foxy.